# Can't see all the font styles installed in Windows 7

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, windows

I've installed a font that has different styles (bold, italics, thin, medium, ultra and so on...), but I can't use them all because I can't see them in Photoshop. The fonts are installed, but seem in some way "overlapped" by windows.

If I open the Windows fonts dir I can see only one style. If I delete it, then a different style appear and so on.

Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You understand that in Photoshop [fonts are fonts and styles are styles](http://i.imgur.com/AD38F.png)? Can you give us an example of one font: how it is shown in Windows dir, what styles should be shown in Photoshop, what are really shown—and how does deleting a font change the situation?

Comment: Do you have several .ttf or .otf files? Is there a clash in the names (internal to the font, some tools shows the font file properties).

Comment: @koiyu: When there's an internal naming conflict, the OS presents the first one it comes across as "the font" and ignores the rest. Delete that one, and the next one on the list then shows up. It's a fragility in the OS's handling of fonts, basically. It would be better if it threw an error so the user would at least know what was happening. Mac OS has a similar problem which has driven many a typographer to drink: e.g., an inadequate system font can't be replaced by a real font with the same name (since Leopard, iirc).

Answer (score 8):

The source of this problem is malformed font files. The internal names of the fonts are in conflict and the flags that indicate connections between the different font files in a typeface family (Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic, etc.) are missing.

The terminology is awkward. Technically and historically "Foo" is a *typeface* and "18 pt Foo Bold Condensed" is a *font*, but in the era of personal computers the definitions have blurred: a typeface is now often referred to as a "font" (even though you'll buy a particular style of that typeface as a "font" in any online store), particularly among non-typographers. The variations tend to be called "styles." People coming newly (last 25 years or so) into design are so used to scaling a font in software that they forget every size of every style of a typeface was once drawn and made individually.

For a regular application (non-professional) to give you the usual "Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic" choices, the font files themselves must be individually named *internally* and the fact that they are associated is a specific internal flag. It's these internal flags that allow you to create bold or italic text with a keyboard shortcut or style dropdown -- the Foo Bold font file tells the OS "I am the Bold version of Foo," and so on.

You have a situation where all the individual font files have the same internal name, so Windows can't differentiate them. You see exactly one font (style) in a family; delete it, and you see another one, and so on. In Word, Open Office, etc., that's probably all you'll see. (Arial Narrow famously suffered from this problem because of an error in creating the files -- it just wouldn't show up at all, or would never show up as an available style for Arial.)

Most non-graphics applications natively understand only the usual four fonts in a family. Additional members (narrow, thin, black, extended, etc.) show up as separate typefaces.

More sophisticated applications such as Photoshop or InDesign know how to read the association flags in a set of font files and can display all the variations in a single dropdown. Garamond Premier Pro, as an example, has 39 font files in four optical sizes -- caption, regular, subhead and display -- that all show up in a single dropdown *if and only if the files themselves contain the correct internal information*. The ones you are having trouble with do not.

The most common source of the problem you are seeing is conversion utilities that don't do a proper job of taking older or other-platform files and turning them into well-formed OpenType or TrueType files. This often affects (illegal, it must be said) Mac --> Windows conversions, because on Mac OS the font information is split between a visible file and a hidden one. If the conversion utility doesn't correctly parse the hidden file, you get a malformed OpenType or TrueType font file that won't work properly on either platform.

Very old and "freebie" font files that are incorrectly set up internally can cause the same issue.

Comment: Thats all well and good but is there a way of editing the font's metadata to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

For me in Windows, Adobe has always had a missing fonts problem: fonts installed are not listed. The solution is to put copies OR SHORTCUTS of the fonts that are missing into the adobe common fonts folder. On my 64-bit machine the default location is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts`

I created a shortcut to my system fonts folder in the above listed folder, and all the previously unlisted fonts are now shown in adobe programs. Using a shortcut ensures that any fonts I add later are automatically scanned by adobe programs upon startup.

Note also that it is typical behavior of well-designed typeface families that if you have a Foobar Sans Bold, it will be automatically selected when you choose "bold" from a type menu (provided the software supports the hinting). In other cases, there will be a dropdown where you can pick the specific special font (regular, bold, italic, smallcaps)

Answer (score 0):

I think this possibly could fix the problem:

"
Start.Run.regedit

navigate to: HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/SessionManager/MemoryManagement

Add a new DWORD named SessionImageSize and set to decimal value 20

reboot and have fun with OpenType ;)

"

Comment: Hi adolfo-  Welcome to GD.  That solution looks interesting for people experiencing trouble installing or uninstalling fonts on XP, but the questioner has already installed the font so this is unlikely to be the issue.