# Where is this font installed?

Tags: fonts, windows

I ran a font previewer (PrintMyFonts) which provides a sample of every font you have installed on your computer. It gives me a sample of Helvetica Narrow, but I can't find the font anywhere to use it! I have a client whose branded font is Helvetica Narrow, so I need to be able to access it. I hate to have to charge them for buying it if it is, in fact, already installed.

It's not available in any application (MS Office or Adobe). Any ideas why it's showing in my PrintMyFonts list of installed fonts but not in any application? Thanks!

Comment: in the "text written in default font" section add: %filepath% | %filename%

Comment: http://www.sttmedia.com/printmyfonts-placeholders

Comment: Also, Adobe products sometimes don't show all installed fonts in their lists. The easy way to fix this is to make a shortcut to the %windir%\fonts folder inside the adobe common fonts folder: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/cant-see-all-the-font-styles-installed-in-windows-7/3070?s=4|0.0679#3070